# Change SharePoint Online Document Preview Pane Height

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, document, properties

Is there a way to modify the document preview height in a Modern SPO document library's information panel?

I am trying to replicate the native Windows File Explorer "Preview Pane" experience as best as I can. Ideally, a full page should be shown in the preview area. See attached photo as a reference.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is no way to customize this panel using SharePoint out of the box settings.

SharePoint does not allow customizing this details pane using JSON formatting or Power apps either.